# Set null the date field while raising exception in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-10

I have validate the `start_date` and `end_date`. I need to set null end date field while raising the error. Here is my code:

```
@api.onchange('end_date')
def onchange_end_date(self, end_date, start_date):
    if (start_date and end_date) and (start_date < end_date):
        raise exceptions.except_orm(_('Warning!'),_('The start date must be less than to the end date.'))
```

Comment: hi Ridma, have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo on-change method you no need to pass any parameter, system will directly get it from self object.

```
@api.onchange('end_date')
def onchange_end_date(self):
    if (self.start_date and self.end_date) and (self.start_date < self.end_date):
        raise exceptions.except_orm(_('Warning!'),_('The start date must be less than to the end date.'))
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try this i hope it helps you

```
import ValidationError

    @api.onchange('end_date')

    def onchange_end_date(self):

        if (self.start_date and self.end_date) and (self.start_date < self.end_date):
            raise ValidationError(''The start date must be less than to the end date.'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Other than onchange we can use constraints... It  helps to validate something when create and edit and also in change..
Here is my code and it works fine

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('start_date', 'start_date')
def _check_date(self):
    start_date = self.start_date
    end_date = self.end_date

    if (start_date and end_date) and (start_date > end_date):
        raise ValidationError(_('The start date must be less than to the end date. '))
```

Thank You